# I keep hitting error while trying to run a model on openvino

Tags: raspberry-pi, openvino

Unknown model format! Cannot find reader for model format: xml and read the model: /home/Danilo/build/open_model_zoo/tools/model_tools/intel/face-detection-adas-0001/FP16/face-detection-adas-0001.xml. Please check that reader library exists in your PATH.

##I was trying to try object detection on raspberry pi and intel neural compute stick 2 but this error kept popping up, how can i get over this error

this was my code
Danilo@red:~/build $ ./armv7l/Release/object_detection_sample_ssd -m ~/build/open_model_zoo/tools/model_tools/intel/face-detection-adas-0001/FP16/face-detection-adas-0001.xml -d MYRIAD -i ~/build/open_model_zoo/tools/model_tools/intel/face-detection-adas-0001/FP16/face-detection-adas-0001.bin

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem, and probably is stems from the wrong information given about the installation process at the official installation site https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_raspbian.html#

There the code reads:

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo
cd open_model_zoo/tools/model_tools
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.in
python3 downloader.py --name face-detection-adas-0001
```

In the response by Intel Support, I spot an important difference: The use of the explicit branching option in the git command (-b 2021.4.2):

```
git clone --depth 1 -b 2021.4.2 https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo
```

This loads the correct model version.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Intermediate Representation (IR) version is same as OpenVINO™ version.

If you're using OpenVINO™ Toolkit 2021.4.2 for Raspbian OS Package, git clone the same version of Open Model Zoo and download the model again:

```
git clone --depth 1 -b 2021.4.2 https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo

cd open_model_zoo/tools/downloader

python3 -m pip install -r requirements.in

python3 downloader.py --name face-detection-adas-0001
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of OpenVINO the error-message has changed... earlier it explicitly reported that the found IR-version is not supported... now it fails with "Unknown model format! Cannot find reader for model format".